# Spring boot Actuator not providing all endpoints in 2.0.0.M5 version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have setup my spring boot project as mentioned in this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/) . I expected it to provide endpoints such as health, metrics etc. Instead it only gives me the following three endpoints. What do I do to get all the endpoints?

Spring boot version : 2.0.0.M5

```
INFO 2017-10-14 01:45:31,176 [main][] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/application/status],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
 INFO 2017-10-14 01:45:31,176 [main][] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/application/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
 INFO 2017-10-14 01:45:31,177 [main][] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/application],methods=[GET]}" onto private java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

Comment: can you give us your application properties file?

Comment: server.port=8080 and managerment.port=9000 are the only properties in it

Comment: AFAIK it can be some spring-boot milestone issue, or you missing some properties...

Comment: I am able to get all endpoints if I change it to version 1.5.7.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable all endpoints by default, you can add the following property:

For **application.properties**:

```
endpoints.default.enabled=true
```

For **application.yml**:

```
endpoints:
  default:
    enabled: true
```

Also you can check out other properties for spring boot 2.0.0.M5 [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M5/reference/htmlsingle/)

Answer (score 3):

The endpoint `/actuator/metrics` was valid only after I added the line `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` to file `application.properties`.

I am using spring-boot-actuator:2.0.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Supplement reference link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints

Answer (score 1):

After I upgrade my spring boot to 2.0.0.M5 apparently only `/status` and `/info` actuator endpoints are enabled by default.

To enable e.g. `/metrics`:

```
endpoints:
  metrics:
    enabled: true
```

Comment: Do you know a way to enable all?

Comment: @Rakesh I think JUANs answer is good. you just need to add **endpoints.default.enabled=true**

Answer (score 1):

The new version to enable endpoints:

`management.endpoints.web.expose=*`